# How to fix WCF error: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission

Tags: wcf, security, trust

I am hosting a netTcpBinding WCF server in a Windows service. I am able to successfully connect to its remote calls via my own client without issue, so I know that it works well.

However, I generate the exception Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission when I attempt to connect to the same service via a .NET plugin fom a third party solution.

My client plugin loaded from the third party application is doing the following:

```
        EndpointAddress endpointAdress = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:2001/MyWCFServer/Server");

        NetTcpBinding binding1 = new NetTcpBinding();

        CTraderClient  _client = new CTraderClient(new InstanceContext(this), binding1, endpointAdress);

         _client.RegisterBotInstance("GBPUSD", 30);
```

where RegisterBotInstance is a call to the remote method exposed by the WCF server.

When I call this remote method _client.RegisterBotInstance("GBPUSD", 30);the following exception is raised:

Additional information: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Action: System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand

Can anyone think of a fix to this?

By the way, the third party application is cAlgo in case this is of any use.

It seems that this third party software has some trust issues.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to add this to the plugin header:

AccessRights = AccessRights.FullAccess