# How to fix exception "Request for the permission of type System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission ... failed"

Tags: c#, .net, securityexception

I am having an issue with a .NET application that dynamically loads dlls (plugins) at runtime. When the application is located on a network drive and is executed from a Windows 10 computer then it would throw the following System.Security.SecurityException:

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed
```

Via debugging I figured out that the exception is thrown when calling the function `Assembly.CreateInstance(string typeName, bool ignoreCase)`

The only solution I found for this issue is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27512051/9284286

However, it would require a lot of time to create a new version of the application and roll it out so I'd prefer a solution that does not require any changes in the application. Is there any way to grant additional permissions to the user who is having this problem or to the computer/system so that the exception no longer occurs?

Comment: Hi Chris, were you able to solve this?